# SQL Server - IF EXISTS executes both the TRUE branch and the FALSE branch

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check if there is an existing record in a table (for an employee evaluation). If such a record exists, the query has to take the latest entry for that employee and calculate the next start date and end date for the next evaluation. If such a record doesn't exist, the query has to apply a different logic and calculate a new start date and end date for the first evaluation (counting back from the current date).

In order to do so, I used the IF EXISTS expression in SQL Server, but it seemed that if I kept the same name for the start date and end date variables, SQL was overwriting them (so was executing the branches sequentially, not picking one or the other). So I declared 2 sets of variables to overcome this issue. However, SQL Server seems to keep on calculating a start date and end date for each case (EXISTS and NOT EXISTS). I know this because I asked it to PRINT the 4 variables, and all were printed with different values.

Here is the declaration of my (now) 4 variables:

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT main.[login] 
        FROM dbo.EVALUATIONS_TABLE eval
        WHERE eval.[login] = @login)
    SET @startdate = DATEADD(day, 1, (SELECT END_DATE FROM (SELECT TOP 1 ID, END_DATE FROM dbo.EVALUATIONS_TABLE WHERE [LOGIN] = @login) lastscorecard));
    SET @enddate = DATEADD(day, 10, @startdate);
ELSE
    SET @startdate_new = DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE());
    SET @enddate_new = DATEADD(day, -10, @startdate_new);
```

I tried to insert the one or the other set of variables in the output table variable, but I still had to rely on the same IF EXISTS logic, which is unreliable as we saw above.
What is the reason why SQL Server gets so confused? I am open to rethinking my entire logic so as to avoid such a mess :-)

Comment: Your snippet of code should be getting an error on `else`, unless this is enclosed in another `if` block.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use BEGIN / END because otherwise only the **first** statement after your IF will be run:

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT main.[login] 
        FROM dbo.EVALUATIONS_TABLE eval
        WHERE eval.[login] = @login) BEGIN
    SET @startdate = DATEADD(day, 1, (SELECT END_DATE FROM (SELECT TOP 1 ID, END_DATE FROM dbo.EVALUATIONS_TABLE WHERE [LOGIN] = @login) lastscorecard));
    SET @enddate = DATEADD(day, 10, @startdate);
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @startdate_new = DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE());
    SET @enddate_new = DATEADD(day, -10, @startdate_new);
END
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, @Allan S. Hansen. I had a feeling this had to to with setting "BEGIN" and "END", but I also read somewhere (maybe in an answer from this site) that BEGIN and END are irrelevant. I realize that I shouldn't consider all use cases as equal. The function is working perfectly now.

Comment: BEGIN / END are definitely not irrelevant :) It might just have been irrelevant in another situation. But, glad to be able to help - and also if the answer helped you, please remember to check one of them as 'accepted'.

Answer (score 1):

The "obvious" solution is to use `begin`/`end` for the if blocks.  In fact, I would recommend *always* using `begin`/`end` with `if` to prevent errors of this type.

But, you can get rid of the `if` altogether:

```
SELECT @startdate = COALESCE(DATEADD(day, 1, MAX(END_DATE)),
                             DATEADD(day, -1 GETDATE)
                            )
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 et.*
      FROM dbo.EVALUATIONS_TABLE et.
      WHERE [LOGIN] = @login
     ) l;

SELECT @enddate = DATEADD(day, -10, @startdate);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gordon, I didn't try your solution yet, but I really want to look into the COALESCE function as it looks like it simplifies the code quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Iulia Mihet, 
You should always use BEGIN and END  for this type of queries. Especially when you are using IF EXISTS query which is conditional. 
Your code should look something like this :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT main.[login] 
    FROM dbo.EVALUATIONS_TABLE eval
    WHERE eval.[login] = @login)
BEGIN
SET @startdate = DATEADD(day, 1, (SELECT END_DATE FROM (SELECT TOP 1 ID, END_DATE FROM dbo.EVALUATIONS_TABLE WHERE [LOGIN] = @login) lastscorecard));
SET @enddate = DATEADD(day, 10, @startdate);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @startdate_new = DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE());
SET @enddate_new = DATEADD(day, -10, @startdate_new);
END
```

Hope It helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use same variables. You have use BEGIN and END. 
Use below query.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT main.[login] 
    FROM dbo.EVALUATIONS_TABLE eval
    WHERE eval.[login] = @login)
BEGIN
    SET @startdate = DATEADD(day, 1, (SELECT END_DATE FROM (SELECT TOP 1 ID, END_DATE FROM dbo.EVALUATIONS_TABLE WHERE [LOGIN] = @login) lastscorecard));
    SET @enddate = DATEADD(day, 10, @startdate);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @startdate = DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE());
    SET @enddate = DATEADD(day, -10, @startdate_new);
END
```